# Retrieving stored images from Firebase and add to custom Listview

Tags: image, listview, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-storage

Im trying to retrieve images from Storage in FireBase, and add them in ListView, but it giving mistake, please help, what Im doing wrong.
Thanks.

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Test");

    mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<HelperFile>(this, HelperFile.class, R.layout.custom_cell, ref) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View view, HelperFile value, int position) {

            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)).setText(value.getXXX());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail)).setText(value.getYYY());
            ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSap)).setText(value.getZZZ());
            //((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate)).setText(value.getDate());

            StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("my Url");
            StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("Images/ooo.jpg");
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageDealer);
            Glide.with(ListView.this)
            .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
            .load(pathReference)
            .into(imageView);
        }

    };

    mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);


}
```

Comment: Can you add the error message that you see?

Comment: Add error message. So that we see where and what is going wrong!

Comment: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must pass in a non null View

Answer (score 0):

If it helps, (I don't know Glide), in Picasso, normally its done like this

```
Picasso.with(context).load(imageLink).into(profilePic);
```

Comment: I had tried picasso as well, result is same, giving mistake.

Comment: Are you getting the proper url from firebase? Try setting a toast or log and check.

Comment: Yes, url showing me image in other action (without Listview) but in ListView gives mistake.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was in ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageDealer);// I add view before findViewById

```
 DatabaseReference ref = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("Test");

mAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<HelperFile>(this, HelperFile.class, R.layout.custom_cell, ref) {
    @Override
    protected void populateView(View view, HelperFile value, int position) {

        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewName)).setText(value.getXXX());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewEmail)).setText(value.getYYY());
        ((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewSap)).setText(value.getZZZ());
        //((TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.textViewDate)).setText(value.getDate());

        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("my Url");
        StorageReference pathReference = storageRef.child("Images/ooo.jpg");
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imageDealer);
        Glide.with(ListView.this)
        .using(new FirebaseImageLoader())
        .load(pathReference)
        .into(imageView);
    }

};
mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

}